# Extract notes and comments of a cell/sheet using excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for a way to extract the notes and comments in an Excel sheet. Almost all the resources in Stack Overflow point to `Range.Comment` which is for extracting notes.

How do I extract all the Notes and Comments of a sheet?
I would also need to extract all the replies from a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Comments" feature in excel is a recent addition to Excel's collaboration capabilities.

Before Excel-online, all the comments relevant to a cell used to be stored as a "Note" (*Right click on cell > Insert Note*). And ironically, the command to extract the text of a cell note using VBA is `Sheet1.Range("A1").Comment.Text`. Now that comments are added as a feature in Excel, this could cause confusion when you want to extract text from a comment.

Below are the resources and info to extract Notes & Comments:

---

### Excel Notes:

You can insert notes in any cell by "*Right Click on cell > New Note*".

**Individual Cell Note:** The command to [extract the text of a Note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.comment.text) of cell A1 is

```
Sheet1.Range("A1").Comment.Text
```

**Selected Sheet Notes:** If you want to extract [all the notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.comments#example) of Worksheet1, you can do so with the following code

```
Worksheets(1).Comments
```

---

### Excel Comments:

You can insert notes in any cell by "*Right Click on cell > New Comment*".

**Individual Cell Comment:** The command to [extract the text of a Comment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.commentthreaded.text) of cell A1 is

```
Sheet1.Range("A1").CommentThreaded.Text
```

**Selected Sheet Notes:** If you want to extract [all the comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.commentsthreaded#example) of Worksheet1, you can do so with the following code

```
Worksheets(1).CommentsThreaded
```

**Replies:** A comment can have multiple replies. So, replies are extracted based on the instance number of the reply. The command to [extract the 1st reply of a Comment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.commentthreaded.replies) of cell A1 is

```
Sheet1.Range("A1").CommentThreaded.Replies(1).Text
```