# Get String from Note / Comment

Tags: excel, vba, string

Since Excel 365 has two types of comments now ([classical notes / comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.comment) and new [threaded comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.commentthreaded)), I'm looking for a convenient way to read any of these and convert them to a simple string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract notes and comments of a cell/sheet using excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68285040/6908282)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each cell, there can be three cases to be considered

- There is no comment at all
- There is a new-style threaded comment
- There is an old-style comment

But there can't be both types of comment on a single cell. The following function returns the comment text (incl. author name and date if available) of the first cell in the given range.

```
Function CommentToString(rng As Range) As String
    Dim c As CommentThreaded
    
    CommentToString = ""  ' fallback in case there is no comment
    If Not rng.Cells(1, 1).CommentThreaded Is Nothing Then
        ' new-style comment
        With rng.Cells(1, 1).CommentThreaded
            CommentToString = .Author.Name & " on " & .Date & ": " & .Text
            For Each c In .Replies
                CommentToString = CommentToString & vbNewLine & _
                    c.Author.Name & " on " & c.Date & ": " & c.Text
            Next c
        End With
    ElseIf Not rng.Cells(1, 1).Comment Is Nothing Then
        ' old-style comment
        With rng.Cells(1, 1).Comment
            ' smart-guess if the comment starts with the author's name, if not prepend it
            If InStr(Left(.Text, Len(.Author)), .Author) > 0 Then
                CommentToString = .Text
            Else
                CommentToString = .Author & ": " & .Text
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Function
```